# How do I unnest a tuple with mixed types?

Tags: python, list, tuples, flatten

I'm trying to flatten a tuple with mixed types into a list. The following function does not produce the desired output:

```
a = (1, 2, 3, ['first', 'second'])
def flatten(l): 
return flatten(l[0]) + (flatten(l[1:]) if len(l) > 1 else []) if type(l) is list else [l]

>>> flatten(a)
[(1, 2, 3, ['first', 'second'])]
>>> flatten(flatten(a))
[(1, 2, 3, ['first', 'second'])]
>>> [flatten(item) for item in a]
[[1], [2], [3], ['first', 'second']]
```

the output should be:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 'first', 'second']
```

Comment: Either that or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python

Comment: Did *none* of the existing questions regarding flattening nested sequences help you? There are quite a few...

Comment: `if type(l) is list` obviously won't work correctly if the input is a tuple, you may want to check `isinstance(l, (list,tuple))` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def flatten(l):
    if isinstance(l, (list,tuple)):
        if len(l) > 1:
            return [l[0]] + flatten(l[1:])
        else:
            return l[0]
    else:
        return [l]

a = (1, 2, 3, ['first', 'second'])

print(flatten(a))
```

> [1, 2, 3, 'first', 'second']